# Method declaration in class files

Tags: java, methods

So I am learning programming myself from the internet.

But I have seen that a lot of times, the tutors use helper methods **before** declaring them.

Here is one example- http://prntscr.com/cbmehs

Now, I have studied javascript before and I believe that the code that we write is read by the compiler from top to bottom and so you cannot declare anything after using it. You **have** to first declare it, only then you can use it.

How then can we use helper methods before declaring/making them?

Comment: Because that's how Java works.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. In Java, declaration-order does not matter for methods.

Comment: so can we declare variables before using them??

Comment: You should have a look at Object Oriented Programming: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Comment: how does java compile then? It has to go from top to bottom right? while doing so, wont it encounter an unknown method as it hasn't been declared **yet**?

Comment: A compiler can do multiple passes over the code. It's possible for it to first only read the function prototypes, then start again from the beginning to read the rest of the code. If you consider class fields as variables, this is again true.

Comment: what is a function prototype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How then can we use helper methods before declaring/making them?

The compiler reads the code many times.

Here's an overview of the process: 
http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/doc/compilation-overview/